# Alterar variavel com programa em execução Python

Tags: python-3.x, variáveis, while, tkinter, booleano

bom to aprendendo python gostaria de saber fazer um botão
que altere a **variavel** que esta rodando no **while**
em tempo real sempre q click no botão sem precisar parar execução

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
ativo = True
class MinhaGUI:
 def __init__(self):
  # Criamos a janela principal
  self.janela_principal = Tk()
  
  # Criando os botões
  self.botao = Button(self.janela_principal, text='Ativado', command=self.ativado)
  self.botao2 = Button(self.janela_principal, text='Desativado', command=self.desativado)
  
  # Empacotando os botões janela principal
  self.botao.pack()
  self.botao2.pack()
  
  # Rodando
  mainloop()

  
 def ativado(self):
  messagebox.showinfo("Msg", "foi ativado")
  ativo = True

 def desativado(self):
  messagebox.showinfo("Msg", "foi desativado")
  ativo = False
gui = MinhaGUI()

while True:
    if(ativo == True):
        print("rodando no ativado")
    elif(ativo == False):
        print("rodando no desativado")
```

Comment: ta um pouco bagunçado, mas tem esse app que fiz, pode servir para algum aprendizado https://github.com/elton1013/dro_fresadora

Comment: `tkinter` cria interfaces orientadas a eventos. No momento que é executado `mainloop()`, o script irá entra em um "modo de espera" e processará todos os eventos da interface que forem capturados. Então o código que está após `gui = MinhaGUI()` não vai ser executado enquanto a janela do `tkinter`  estiver aberta. Se você quer mudar alguma variável como resposta a eventos na interface gráfica, terá que fazer por meio de funções que respondem a esses eventos (como os métodos `ativado` e `desativado` que você já fez).